# .htaccess allow if else with self host?

Tags: php, .htaccess

When someone accesses example.pdf they get redirected to viewer.php. viewer.php should be able to access the pdf file. However, the .htaccess file causes the viewer.php file to not be able to access the pdf because of the redirect and gets caught in a loop.

Is there a way to add the following logic to .htaccess:

if(host = myserver)
     do not redirect pdf
else
     redirect pdf to viewer.php

thanks

Here is my htacces file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.pdf$  web/viewer.php?pdf=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
AddType application/octet-stream .pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I've taken a look at the libraries source and it isn't your server making the request to the PDF, it's the javascript which will be a client side request unfortunately and therefore this won't be as easy as I think you were hoping for! (Ie you can't just check for 127.0.0.1 as it will be users' IP addresses).

I'm not sure how it would work properly, but one option could be to update all of the PDF files adding an extra character to the file extension (so instead of .pdf it's .pdfs or similar). You could then update your RewriteRule adding an "s" after the $1 like so:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.pdf$  web/viewer.php?pdf=$1s [L,NC,QSA]
```

This is assuming that the pdf.js script is able to render files without the extension .pdf.

---

Try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^127.0.0.1$
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.pdf$  web/viewer.php?pdf=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
AddType application/octet-stream .pdf
```

Comment: By the way, I am assuming your script is doing `file_get_contents` to load the file (via HTTP) it would be better to use `fopen` and push the local file's contents to the web browser.

Comment: Thank you but I still having trouble. Do I need to change any part of this htaccess file for it to work for me? I am using the pdf.js library (http://mozilla.github.com/pdf.js/) which works fine until I use redirectengine (assuming infinite loop)

Comment: Try my updated version, I've added a 301 redirect see if that works. I wouldn't of thought this would be infinite loop though, but i guess it depends on the pdf.js source code.

Comment: What is the source of your viewer.php file?

Comment: Actually I've checked the pdf.js and I've updated my answer - i don't think this is going to be as simple as you expected!

Comment: how about checking the referrer?

Comment: Referrer won't be consistent and some browsers won't show it, you'll end up with a lot of frustrated users. Some virus programs remove it from all requests for example.